# The "underscore"\"hash" meaning in RDoc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, documentation, rdoc

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I am trying to understand how the **RDoc** system works. So I would like to understand what the "hash" value means when the [official documentation](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/doc/) refers to that on line 7:

> 1. Names of classes, source files, and any method names containing an
>      underscore or preceded by a **hash**
>      character are automatically
>      hyperlinked from comment text to their
>      description.

**Can you make me an example of stating that in my commented code? Have you some advice about using that?**

---

**BTW**: Do you have a "MUST READ" resource referring to RDoc? If so, can you provide that?

Answer (score 2):

They mean the `#` symbol.

When referring to a method in text, it is typical for you to prepend a hash to it. For example: "In order to convert array to a string, call #to_s". Now, rdoc will notice the hash and turn it into a link to the documentation for the method `to_s`.

Comment: The notation using hash allows you to mention instance methods without refering to a particular instance, e.g., `Array#to_s`. It allows you to distinguish it from `Array#to_s`, which will mean class/module method.

Comment: @sawa, Do you mean to distinguish from Array.to_s?